# ExpressJs custom middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I code a custom validation middleware function name is **validator.js** for `express.js`.

```
/* validator.js */
const body  = (check_this) => new Body(check_this)
const Body = function(check_this) {
    this.minLength = (length) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            if(req.body[check_this] && req.body[check_this].length < length) // do something here
            next()
        }
    }

    this.maxLength = (length) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            if(req.body[check_this] && req.body[check_this].length > length) // do something here
            next()
        }
    }
}
module.exports = { body }
```

It can be call in `router.js` as follow.

```
/* router.js */
const { body } = require("./validator")
router.post("/change-password", [
    body("password").minLength(6),
    body("password").maxLength(8)
], function(req, res) {
    /* other code */
})
```

But I want to call it like this.

```
/* router.js */
const { body } = require("./validator")
router.post("/change-password", [
    body("password").minLength(6).maxLength(8)
], function(req, res) {
    /* other code */
})
```

How to edit my code? Can anyone give me some example code?

Comment: I think adding return this below next() should do the trick.

Comment: @Bergur, I have already tried with `return this`. But not work. It return only function

Comment: can you try `return next(this)`. Basically, the thing that you want to do is chaining of functions in JS and the base of it returning `this` in every function. This may work.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh, I tried function chaining and method chaining. It should be return like this `body { ... }`. But it return `function (anonymous)`